# Скачивание картинок Android Webview

Tags: android, webview

Возможно ли сделать, чтобы при открытии через `WebView` url изображения была возможность скачать его на устройство?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю смысл таков: у картинки загруженной в вебвью есть адрес URL по которому она храниться на сервере. Можно попробовать распарсить страничку, которая загружается в вебвью(хз, я лично не пробовал это) и вытащить адрес картинки. После чего скачивать картинку по этому адресу если конечно сайт их отдаст.

Comment: все парсить не обязательно, надо будет писать на джаваскрипте и если клик на картинке, взять ее урл и сохранить картинку на карту памяти, как то так.

Comment: вполне может быть. Главное чтобы автор понял вектор мысли правильный) То что это возможно думаю не вызывает сомнений.

Answer (score 2):

В     WebView

```
 myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptInterface(getActivity()), "imagelistner");
 myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                        addImageClickListner();
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                        myWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
```

и в класс

```
     private void addImageClickListner() {
        myWeb.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
                "var objs = document.getElementsByTagName(\"img\"); " +
                "for(var i=0;i<objs.length;i++)  " +
                "{"
                + "    objs[i].onclick=function()  " +
                "    {  "
                + "        window.imagelistner.openImage(this.src);  " +
                "    }  " +
                "}" +
                "})()");
    }

    public class JavascriptInterface {

        private Context context;


        public JavascriptInterface(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
        public void openImage(String img) {
         DownloadManager.Request rqtRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(img));
    rqtRequest.setNotificationVisibility(    DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    ((DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).enqueue(rqtRequest);
        }
    }
```

В openImage можно что угодно делать с строкой , я послал в стандартный загрузчик